# Javascript Random image with text on click button

Tags: javascript, function, button, random, hyperlink

I've been following some other tutorials and managed to get an image combined with specific text to display on load and a different image and combined text after refresh.

But now i want to connect it to a button so the random combination of text and image only show on click, the button doesn't do anything.

Javascript in the head tags

```html
<div id="quote"></div>


    <input class="Randombutton" style="float: left;" type="button" 
    value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg()">
    
    
    
    <script>
    (function randomImg() {
      var quotes = [
        {
          text: "BIO1",
          img:  "images/captainamerica.jpg"
        },
        {
          text: "BIO2",
          img:  "images/hulk.jpg",
        },
  {
          text: "BIO3",
          img:  "images/spiderman.jpg",
        },
  {
          text: "BIO4",
          img:  "images/blackwidow.jpg",
        },
  {
          text: "BIO5",
          img:  "images/ironman.png",
        },
      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
    })();
    </script>
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where's your element with the ID of `quote`? Why do you have a closing script tag after your button? Why are you immediately invoking your function in the head of the page?

Comment: Sorry we are being thought a specific (wrong) way in college by the lecturer. Your comment helped me realise simple mistakes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet what you need?

```js
function randomImg() {
      var quotes = [
        {
          text: "BIO1",
          img:  "images/captainamerica.jpg"
        },
        {
          text: "BIO2",
          img:  "images/hulk.jpg",
        },
  {
          text: "BIO3",
          img:  "images/spiderman.jpg",
        },
  {
          text: "BIO4",
          img:  "images/blackwidow.jpg",
        },
  {
          text: "BIO5",
          img:  "images/ironman.png",
        },
      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
    }
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>


    <input class="Randombutton" style="float: left;" type="button" 
    value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg()">
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Will mark as answer when available.